# how to clear google map marker cache in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have more than 400 marker on the google map, and I use the loop to set each marker to setMap(null), but there are always a few on the google map.I then set the rest of the marker in the chrome console to setMap(null), which still doesn't work.

My code is as follows

```
 let marker = OBJECT.CustomerList;
        marker.forEach( function ( value ,index ) {
           OBJECT.CustomerList[index].setMap(null);

 })
```

Comment: Did you check this?https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Comment: I refer to the official document, but it still has no effect.I tried to show 50 on the map, and when I removed them,  still had one on the map.

Comment: Can you show demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
const mark= OBJECT.CustomerList;
for (let i = 0; i < mark.length; i++) {
          (function(index){
              mark[index].setMap(null);
          })(i)
  }
```

Comment: Also see this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove